# I want to overlap two div like the image given below

Tags: html, css

This is just a rough code I did using html and css.
How to overlap the green div at top of white div? 
I tried moving the green div up, but when i give more px to margin-bottom, it doesn't move up

```css
#d3{
 background-color: white;
 border:0px solid transparent;
 width:500px;
 height:200px;
 
 
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
 
}

#d4{
 background-color: green;
 border:0px solid transparent;
 width:450px;
 height:50px;
 z-index:1;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p id="i3">Tabs with icons</p><br><br><br>
      <div id="d3">
        <br><br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mattis nunc ligula nullam, sagittis dapibus magna feugiat, sit vel rutrum eros lacus vestibulum. Diam mauris venenatis ultricies, a donec fames placerat eget lacus dis, ut vestibulum, malesuada odio sem elementum erat nunc et, risus metus tortor vel in. Vestibulum in, nunc eu sed congue tincidunt dui, vulputate lectus nam ipsum. Justo donec, phasellus vitae tellus, felis duis massa fermentum, eu sem enim. Magna justo, est lectus non laoreet venenatis porta sed, pulvinar sit nulla enim, mauris duis nulla laoreet velit. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="d4">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruFfw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you wrap your `div`'s and switch their order in the markup to how they lay out on page.

The wrapper, being positioned relative, will flow with the rest of your content and the "green" `div` can be properly positioned using absolute positioning.

A padding on the 2:nd `div` will push its content in position.

*Note, it is also possible to use negative margins to position the "green" `div`, though if and how depends on how you intend to use it.*

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
#d3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: -25px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#d4 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 35px 10px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
}
```

```html
<p id="i3">Tabs with icons</p>
<br>
<br>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="d3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </div>
  <div id="d4">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mattis nunc ligula nullam, sagittis dapibus magna feugiat, sit vel rutrum eros lacus vestibulum. Diam mauris venenatis ultricies, a donec fames placerat eget lacus dis, ut vestibulum, malesuada odio sem elementum erat nunc
      et, risus metus tortor vel in. Vestibulum in, nunc eu sed congue tincidunt dui, vulputate lectus nam ipsum. Justo donec, phasellus vitae tellus, felis duis massa fermentum, eu sem enim. Magna justo, est lectus non laoreet venenatis porta sed, pulvinar
      sit nulla enim, mauris duis nulla laoreet velit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/ae87epxw/) an example which shows what you're after.

To change your own example to work, simply change the `margin-top` on your `#d4` to be `-225px` (half of its height).

```
margin-top: -225px;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use:

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
```

on the #d4 element. Adjust the top as needed to position on top of the d4 element.

I've updated your code below, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) is a good reference for how positioning like this works

```css
#d3{
 background-color: white;
 border:0px solid transparent;
 width:500px;
 height:200px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
 
}

#d4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
 background-color: green;
 border:0px solid transparent;
 width:450px;
 height:50px;
 z-index:1;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p id="i3">Tabs with icons</p><br><br><br>
      <div id="d3">
        <br><br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mattis nunc ligula nullam, sagittis dapibus magna feugiat, sit vel rutrum eros lacus vestibulum. Diam mauris venenatis ultricies, a donec fames placerat eget lacus dis, ut vestibulum, malesuada odio sem elementum erat nunc et, risus metus tortor vel in. Vestibulum in, nunc eu sed congue tincidunt dui, vulputate lectus nam ipsum. Justo donec, phasellus vitae tellus, felis duis massa fermentum, eu sem enim. Magna justo, est lectus non laoreet venenatis porta sed, pulvinar sit nulla enim, mauris duis nulla laoreet velit. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="d4">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

you need to add `position:relative` to `#d3` and add those lines to `#d4`:

```
position:absolute;
  bottom:70px;
  left:6px;
```

here you have a working snippet:

```css
#d3{
 background-color: white;
 border:0px solid transparent;
 width:500px;
 height:200px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  position:relative;
 
}

#d4{
 background-color: green;
 border:0px solid transparent;
 width:450px;
 height:50px;
 z-index:1;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
 white-space: nowrap;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:70px;
  left:6px;
  
}
```

```html
<p id="i3">Tabs with icons</p><br><br><br>
      <div id="d3">
        <br><br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mattis nunc ligula nullam, sagittis dapibus magna feugiat, sit vel rutrum eros lacus vestibulum. Diam mauris venenatis ultricies, a donec fames placerat eget lacus dis, ut vestibulum, malesuada odio sem elementum erat nunc et, risus metus tortor vel in. Vestibulum in, nunc eu sed congue tincidunt dui, vulputate lectus nam ipsum. Justo donec, phasellus vitae tellus, felis duis massa fermentum, eu sem enim. Magna justo, est lectus non laoreet venenatis porta sed, pulvinar sit nulla enim, mauris duis nulla laoreet velit. </p>
          <div id="d4">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      
        </div>
```